# Rack custom middleware giving error "ActionDispatch::Http::Parameters::ParseError"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, rack

I am writing a custom middleware for my rails app, to decrypt/encrypt parameters in a post request. I have configured the middleware in `'config/environments/staging.rb'`

```
config.middleware.use CustomMiddleware
```

In order to read the request params i am reading the env obj like this

```
rack_input = env['rack.input'].read
```

I am able to access the parameter and manipulate as needed. But when i pass over on the `env` obj to the app object which is the receiver. I am getting

```
"ActionDispatch::Http::Parameters::ParseError"
```

Full error

```
Error occurred while parsing request parameters.
Contents:


F, [2017-11-15T02:13:50.230088 #24060] FATAL -- : [9aa25c7e-56e7-4894-ba30-3a01f60ae4fc]   
F, [2017-11-15T02:13:50.230340 #24060] FATAL -- : [9aa25c7e-56e7-4894-ba30-3a01f60ae4fc] ActionDispatch::Http::Parameters::ParseError (no implicit conversion of nil into String):
F, [2017-11-15T02:13:50.230563 #24060] FATAL -- : [9aa25c7e-56e7-4894-ba30-3a01f60ae4fc]   
F, [2017-11-15T02:13:50.230782 #24060] FATAL -- : [9aa25c7e-56e7-4894-ba30-3a01f60ae4fc] app/middleware/custom_middleware.rb:34:in `call'
```

My code is somewhat like this

```
class CustomMiddleware
  include Encryption   

  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def set_payload_params(env)
    rack_input = env['rack.input'].read
    @args = JSON.parse(rack_input) rescue {}
  end

  def call(env)
    request = Rack::Request.new(env)
    set_payload_params(env)

    payload = @args['payload']

    decrypt_params
    status, headers, response = @app.call(env)
    encrypt_params

  end
```

If i don't read the env object and hard code the parameters, there is no such parsing error. And my controller is responding with data w.r.t to hardcode parameters.

My Rails version is 5.1.4
My ruby version is 2.4.2

I have done a similar middleware in another rails app(4.2.8) which is working fine.

Any insight on this will be of much help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs cause after params are empty after read in middleware (this is stream).

```
rack_input = env['rack.input'].read
```

After execute this code rack params are blank. Now you need to make

```
env['rack.input'].rewind
```

or

```
request.body.rewind
```

Now your request has params again and Rails can simply continue job.

Answer (score 0):

Added a hack to set content-type as "" in custom middleware, which avoided  parsing on the input before forwarding the input to next component in the stack.

```
 class CustomMiddleware   

   include Encryption   

   def initialize(app)
     @app = app   end

   def set_payload_params(env)
     rack_input = env['rack.input'].read
     @args = JSON.parse(rack_input) rescue {}   end

   def call(env)
     env['CONTENT_TYPE'] = ''
     request = Rack::Request.new(env)
     set_payload_params(env)

     payload = @args['payload']

     decrypt_params
     status, headers, response = @app.call(env)
     encrypt_params

  end
```